# sidekiq retries exhausted with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I crawl `leads` from other sites and *activate* them at mine. With `Sidekiq` I run a  `HealthCheckerWorker` every hour to *deactivate* the lead on my site unless it's still up and running on the other site.

Sometimes the `HealthCheckerWorker` throws an error, iE: `bad URI` etc... My dilemma here is that if the job fails 10 times, now in the Dead Job Queue, the `lead` is still considered *active* although it may be long gone on the other site.

I thought the solution would be to add a `sidekiq_retries_exhausted` block like so:

```
sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |lead_id|
  Lead.find(lead_id).deactivate
end
```

But as defined in the [docs:](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling)

> The hook receives the queued message as an argument. This hook is called right before Sidekiq moves the job to the DJQ.

So it only gets the `message` as an argument. How can I *deactivate* the lead after the retries are exhausted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The message is the entire job, including the arguments.  Just pull out the arguments.

```
sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
  lead_id = msg['args'].first
  Lead.find(lead_id).deactivate
end
```

Comment: jup, thanks allot :) great work btw, in love with the tool haha

Comment: For reference you'd call message['args']

Comment: how did you write specs for this?

Comment: how did you write specs for this?